# Plotting multiple figures in Matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, rhel, matlab-figure

I am working with some matlab code that processes data (in a Kalman Filter) and creates a series of contour plots. It has been running on a RHEL 4 server in matlab 2006a for a few years, but my boss recently requested that all servers be updated to RHEL 6...and at least matlab 2007a. I have worked out all the depreciations  between these versions, but I am still having one major problem.

The code that creates and prints different contour plots is working for whichever of the three plots is created first. It looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately the next two plots look like this:

[image]

The three figures are plotted independently in separate functions and I use `clf("reset");` before and after creating each figure. Each function works in and of itself, but when all three are plotted the second and third figures are all messed up. Has anyone else had this problem? Here is the code that creates one of the figures.

```
function Crd = TEC_plot(ITEC,RT,Param,Input,t,OutPath,RxExtAll,Time)
% Generate TEC plot 
    Function_for_Spline_Smoothing = [.05 .1 .05; .1 .4 .1; .05 .1 .05];
    ITEC = conv2(ITEC,Function_for_Spline_Smoothing,'same'); % add more of these lines to make contours smoother
    ITEC = conv2(ITEC,Function_for_Spline_Smoothing,'same'); % add more of these lines to make contours smoother
%   ITEC = conv2(ITEC,Function_for_Spline_Smoothing,'same'); % add more of these lines to make contours smoother
%   ITEC = conv2(ITEC,Function_for_Spline_Smoothing,'same'); % add more of these lines to make contours smoother

    earth('CAMERA',RT.Camera,'FIG',1);
    figure;
    warning off; hold on;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Changed 13 February 2007 to make plots prettier
    thinning_scale=2; % (1 to 10) increase this value to thin the density of the contour number labels
    [cscale,hgt]=m_contour(Param.Grid.LonAxis,Param.Grid.LatAxis,ITEC, ...
       round(RT.Levels(1:thinning_scale:end)/5)*5);
    hold on
    m_contourf(Param.Grid.LonAxis,Param.Grid.LatAxis,ITEC,RT.Levels);
    shading flat

    m_coast('line','color','y','LineWidth',1); 

    clabel(cscale,hgt,'labelspacing',72,'rotation',0,'fontsize',10 ...
                      ,'FontAngle','italic','color','w');
    axis([-.65 .6 .25 1.32])    % hardwiring axis length since the coastline runs off of the plot
% Changed 13 February 2007
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% %-------------------- to include different station markers for different sources -------------------
    if ~isempty(Input.Data) % Plot receivers used in this inversion

        Crd=uniquerows(double(cat(1,RxExtAll)));
        RxType=round(Crd(:,4));
        Crd=cartsph(Crd)*180/pi;

        i1 = find( (Crd(:,3) > RT.Camera(3)).*(Crd(:,3) < RT.Camera(4)).*...
                  (Crd(:,2) > RT.Camera(1)).*(Crd(:,2) < RT.Camera(2)).*...
                  (RxType==1) );

        i2 = find( (Crd(:,3) > RT.Camera(3)).*(Crd(:,3) < RT.Camera(4)).*...
                  (Crd(:,2) > RT.Camera(1)).*(Crd(:,2) < RT.Camera(2)).*...
                  (RxType==2) );

        i3 = find( (Crd(:,3) > RT.Camera(3)).*(Crd(:,3) < RT.Camera(4)).*...
                  (Crd(:,2) > RT.Camera(1)).*(Crd(:,2) < RT.Camera(2)).*...
                  (RxType==3) );

        m_plot(Crd(i1,3),Crd(i1,2),'ro','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);
%       m_plot(Crd(i1,3),Crd(i1,2),'r.','markersize',6,'LineWidth',2);
        m_plot(Crd(i2,3),Crd(i2,2),'r^','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);
%       m_plot(Crd(i2,3),Crd(i2,2),'r.','markersize',6,'LineWidth',2);
        m_plot(Crd(i3,3),Crd(i3,2),'rp','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);

        plot(-.6,.45,'ro','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);text(-.55,.45,'CORS','Color','k')
        plot(-.6,.39,'r^','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);text(-.55,.39,'GPS/Met','Color','k')
        plot(-.6,.33,'rp','markersize',5,'LineWidth',2);text(-.55,.33,'RTIGS','Color','k')

    end
% % ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    hold off; warning on;axis off;

%   caxis([RT.Levels(1),(RT.Levels(length(RT.Levels)))/2]); colorbar('vert');  %Color bar from 0 to 50 --- for Low Solar Activity
    caxis([RT.Levels(1),(RT.Levels(length(RT.Levels)))]); colorbar('vert');  %Color bar from 0 to 100 --- for High Solar Activity

    title(sprintf('Total Electron Content Units x 10^1^6 m^-^2'),'Fontsize',11)
    if size(Crd,1)==0,
        title(sprintf('Total Electron Content Units x 10^1^6 m^-^2 Caution: No Data Available, IRI95 Only'),'Fontsize',10)
    end
    whitebg('w')
    text(-0.6,0.22,sprintf('%s from %s to %s UT           NOAA/SWPC Boulder, CO USA (op.ver. 1.0)',datestr(Time(t)+1E-8,1),datestr(Time(t)+1E-8,15),datestr(Time(t)+1E-7+15/1440,15)),'Fontsize',11)
    whitebg('w')

% This option print to a file
%        set(gcf, 'Position', [0,0,1950,1467]);
%        print('-f1','-dpng','-painters',filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC'],Time(t)));
%        system(['convert ', filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.png'],Time(t)),' -scale 650x489 ',' -colors 256 ', filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.png'],Time(t))]);


% Printing a postscript file because requirements for the automatic reboot
    print('-f1','-dpsc','-r1000','-painters', filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC'],Time(t)));

% Convert the postscript file to jpg using ghostscripts
    system(['gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=',filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.jpg'],Time(t)),' ', filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.ps'],Time(t))]);
% Converting from jpg to png and reducing the size of the figure.
    system(['convert ',filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.jpg'],Time(t)),' -crop 2050x1675+325+775 ',' -scale 650x489 ',' -colors 256 ', filename([OutPath,'{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HRMN}_TEC.png'],Time(t))]);
% Removing the jpg and ps files (ask Cliff how can we put both files in just one command)
    %system(['rm ',filename([OutPath,'*.jpg'],Time(t))]);
    %system(['rm ',filename([OutPath,'*.ps'],Time(t))]); 
end
```

Comment: Sure we'd like to see some code Oo

Comment: why does the code look like that? I just added a code section and pasted in the code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not use `clf` which will clear your whole figure but use the `figure` in between to open three independant figures. See it it'll work :)

Edit: That's just guessing without actually seeing your code

Comment: I'm trying it now. Seeing as this is running on a command line only interface with no UI, will 'figure' try to create a new window and return an error?

Comment: `figure` simply opens another figure window and all plot-commands will be plotted within the new figure. So you'd have 3 different windows afterwards instead of always clearing the same figure and than replotting data into it

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The first figure only shows coast lines and the second two are completely blank :/ Hmmmm. Also how do you clear a figure window once in has saved the image?

Comment: Do I have to specify which window to plot in?

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. If not specified, always being plotted to the `current figure` (i.e. the last opened one)

Comment: OK so it is still creating the second two plots as blank. Am I using figure in the right place? Are the holds in the right place? I'm really stumped here. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I realized that the 'earth()' function specifies a figure number...that was the problem all along! Thanks so much for your help! I'm having a different problem now regarding the boarder around the figure but I'll start a new thread for that problem and post the link here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One guess might be with the code that generates your final PNG file.  Your second figure appears to be incorrectly cropped when converting from JPG to PNG.

First the `print` command is fixed to use whatever is in figure 1. So, to ensure that you are plotting using figure 1 use the command `figure(1)` to specify this. Alternatively, change the print command to to read `print(gcf ...` to print the current figure.

Also, note you could generate the PNG file directly with `print` as in

```
print(gcf,'-dpng','-r1000',filename(...))
```

and skip the conversion from PS to JPG to PNG step.

The hard-coding the figure window in the `print` might explain why things work independently but not together if the you have multiple figure windows available. Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advise! I didn't end up doing exactly what you said but you did push me in the right direction. I ended up defining each figure number manually and by doing that I found that the 'earth()' function specifies a figure number...changed that and now thing are running much smoother. Thanks! Oh and the conversions from ps->jpg->png are annoying but necessary for other reasons. I am still running into some other problems with these plots but I'll start a new thread for that and post a link here. Thanks again.